Download directly to starred folders?
I would like to download files from Firefox directly to folders that are starred. Currently it opens up a window that doesn't have that option, and also doesn't allow for single click opening like in the normal filesystem.
How can I make that happen?
Thanks.
P.s. - Here is the window in question:

I would like to add a "Starred" option as the save path.
*Firefox version 125.0.2 Snap version

Well I'll take it back: I just noticed chromium apparently does it. So I went deeper and found out that "Starred locations" (which really are called GTK bookmarks) are a GTK thing, not a Nautilus-specific thing, and that they're listed in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks. And sure enough, when I tried running Firefox... I do get the list unlike you. Which version of Firefox do you have installed? Mine is the snap version from Mozilla

Firefox version 124.0.2-1

@kos Updated with FF version: 125.0.2 Snap as of today. Pretty sure there was an update between now and when you commented. So you got it to work?
